# Polnareff & Kakyoin`s Speech to J.Geil, せるふ?

Tags: anime

I was watching JoJo`s Bizarre Adventure and during Polnareff's speech to J.Giel(link here: https://youtu.be/y-Ov19GvGo0?t=22s) he says 22 seconds in: この場合そうゆう and then he says what i hear as: "せるふゆうんじゃね" but i looked せるふ up and it's only definition is self, so i was wondering is that what he really said or am i hearing it incorrectly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

セリフ

> ejje.weblio.jp/content/台詞 -- 
>    ‎
>   台詞を英語に訳すと 
>    1〈俳優の〉(a) speech; words; one's line(s) 
>   台詞のない役をする do [have] a nonspeaking [walk‐on] part 
>   台詞を言うspeak one's ...

---

【ジョジョ 】ポルナレフの台詞だけでコメント100を目指す | ジョジョ速

jojosoku.com/archives/42570568.html
‎

2015年2月13日 ... この場合！そういうセリフをいうんじゃねえいいか…こういう場合！かたきを討つ時という
 のはいまからいうようなセリフをはいて たたかうんだ…… 『我が名はJ・P・ポルナレフ』 『
 我が妹の魂の名誉のために！』 『我が友アヴドゥルの心のやすらぎ ...

---

ジャン＝ピエール・ポルナレフ|ジョジョの奇妙な冒険(集英社文庫)|名言 ...

koryamata.jp/wordmanager/27/ch497.html

‎
(ポルナレフ) おい花京院…… この場合!そういうセリフをいうんじゃねえ (J・ガイル) ? (
 ポルナレフ) いいか…こういう場合! かたきを討つ時というのはいまからいうようなセリフ
 をはいて たたかうんだ…… 『我が名はJ・P・ポルナレフ』 『我が妹の魂の名誉のために!』